# Why don't I get a calclatefee result? Is my Array value overriding my overridden method?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am trying to output calclatefee of $2 per day after 3 days. I have switched things around and I am left at this which looks a little sloppy. This Array is also making me take the confusing way.

```
public class Movie {

    String rating;
    String title;
    int id;
    int rentTime;

    public String setrating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void rating(String getrating) {
        rating = getrating;
    }

    public int setid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void id(int agetid) {
        id = agetid;
    }

    public String settitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void title(String gettitle) {
        title = gettitle;
    }

    public int setfees() {
        return rentTime;
    }

    public void fees(int getrentTime) {
        rentTime = getrentTime;
    }

    public Movie() {
        title = "  ";
        rating = "  ";
        id = 0;
        rentTime = 0;
        System.out.println("default constructor");
    }

    public Movie(String title, String rating, int id, int rentTime) {
        title = " not overridden ";
        rating = " NR ";
        id = 0;
        rentTime = 0;
        System.out.println("Overloaded -" + title + rating + id + rentTime);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Movie[] Array = { 
                new Action(" The 100", " pg-13", 105, 7, 3),
                new Comedy(" Supernatural", " pg-13", 5, 2, 0), 
                new Drama(" Lost 2", " R", 9, 2, 0) };

        for (int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++) {
            // System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(Array[x].toString());

        }
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class Action extends Movie {

    protected double latecost;
    protected double latefees = 3;

    public Action(String gettitle, String getrating, int getid, int getrentTime, double latecost) {

        super(gettitle, getrating, getid, getrentTime);
        title = gettitle;
        rating = getrating;
        id = getid;
        rentTime = getrentTime;
        latecost = latefees;

        System.out.println("Overridden " + title + rating + " " + id + " " + " " + rentTime + " "
                + latecost);
    }

    public double calclatefees(double latecost, double rentTime) {
        if (rentTime > 3)
            latefees = ((rentTime - 3) * latecost);
        return latefees;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String x = "\nMovie: " + title + " is rated " + rating + "\nMovie ID        number: " + id
                + " and the late fee for action movies is $" + latecost + "\n";
        return x;
    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {

        try {
            System.out.println("Finalize method");
        } finally {
            super.finalize();
        }
    }

    public void dispose() {
        System.out.println(" dispose method");
    }
}
```

Comment: I now see that you are continually asking the same question on this site. Please stop doing this as this is very unfair to the volunteers who might put in effort to help you. You are essentially asking folks to duplicate work that's already been done before. Continue with this behavior and no one will want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- There's no calclatefee method to override in the parent class. If you want a child class to override method, it must be present in the parent class, at least as an abstract method (if the parent is abstract or is an interface).
- You never call your calclatefee method anywhere, so you shouldn't expect to ever see its result in your output.
- Your child class, Action, is abstract -- isn't that backwards? Most often its the parent class that's abstract, so why are you structuring it this way? And as written your main method shouldn't compile since you seem to be trying to create an instance of an abstract class.
- Your class overrides the `finalize()` method, something that is generally [not recommended](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/288715/is-overriding-object-finalize-really-bad). Fortunately your override doesn't really do anything other than output to the standard out and then call the super's method, but still, why risk it?
- Side issues

  1. Your code does not follow [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.
  2. You will want to try to improve the formatting of your code that you post in here and your code in general. Good formatting including using an indentation style that is uniform and consistent will help others (**us**!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, it will help **you** to better understand your code and thus fix your own bugs. Also it shows that you're willing to put in extra effort to make it easier for the volunteers here to help you, and that effort is **much** appreciated. I took the liberty of trying to fix this for you.

Comment: Have the initiated calclatefees in the parent class, fixed the abstract issue and have proper formatting. What would I need in the parent class to make the calclatefees work? I am unclear about your issue with my finalize method. I have videos where calculatefees is output based on the return value, why can't I do it that way?